# Bash script returning wrong output for file size

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have this simple script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

flimit=157286400 #150MB limit size
fsize=$(stat -c%s $0)

if [ "$fsize" -gt "$flimit" ]; then
   echo "File size is greater than expected."
else
   echo "File size is OK"
fi

echo "The file size is $fsize"
```

Basically, it receives a file as argument (`$0`) and check if it is greater than a specified limit of 150mb.

When i run it with `./checksize.sh my_file.zip`, i get this output:

```
File size is OK.
The size of this file is 220
```

`my_file.zip` has 153MB. I don't know where this 220 came from and if it was expected.

Thanks

Comment: You are referring to the  first argument as `$0` , but it is `$1`. `$0` is the name of the command run, so 220 will be the size of your shell script.

Comment: Oh, thank you for a rapid and clear response.

Comment: I recommend using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone program on many Linux distributions, to "proof-read" shell scripts. It certainly helps me catch a lot of errors.